# Implementing Try Catch for no input and invalid input

Tags: c#, try-catch

I want to do this because I would like to block inputs that will crash my program. I tried doing it like this but I get the errors use of unassigned parameter total and the out parameter totalstring  and total must be assigned before control leaves current method.

```
private static void Start(out String totalString, out int total) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How Many ? (2-4)");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        try
        { totalString = Console.ReadLine();
            total = int.Parse(totalString);


        }
        catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        bool flag = false;

        if ((total <= 1) || (total > 4)) //loop to reject invaid input
            while (flag == false)
            {

                if ((total <= 1) || (total > 4))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. How many?");


                    totalString = Console.ReadLine();
                    total = int.Parse(totalString);

                    Console.Clear();

                }

                else if ((total >= 2) || (total <= 4))
                {

                    flag = true;
                }
            }

 Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Player Numbers :" + total); 
        Console.WriteLine();

        players = new Player[total];
    }
}
}
```

Sorry about that :)

Comment: your code doesn't seem to show us where the error occurs

Comment: Show the complete method. Plus your errors are **semantic errors** and can be solved by simple searching on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`:

Terse:

```
 int total;

 do {
   Console.WriteLine("How Many ? (2-4)");
 }
 while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out total) && (total >= 2) && (total <= 4)))
```

Talkative:

```
  int total;

  Console.WriteLine("How Many ? (2-4)");

  while (true) {
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out total)) {
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. How many?");    
    else if ((total < 2) || (total > 4)) {
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid range. How many?");  
    else
      break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a method that has `out` parameters, then you must always assign a value to them, whatever path your code takes. This is what that error message is trying to tell you.

When you have

```
   try
    { totalString = Console.ReadLine();
        total = int.Parse(totalString);
```

and "Console.ReadLine()" throws an error, then both `totalString` and `total` are not assigned. Similarly, when the ReadLine succeeds, but the int.Parse fails, then `total` is not assigned.

Simple solution: assign default values at the start of the method:

```
totalString = null;
total = 0;
```

These will be overwritten when everything works out.

Answer (score 0):

There are two improvements you can make here:

1 Get rid of the `out` parameters and return the player array, rather than having a void method.

2 Use a `do while` loop instead of the current code:

```
private static IEnumerable<Player> Start() 
{
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How Many ? (2-4)");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        try
        { 
            var totalString = Console.ReadLine();
            var total = int.Parse(totalString);
            if (total >= 1 && total <= 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number of players :" + total);
                return new Player[total];
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        }
    } while (true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `total` is never assigned to if `int.Parse()` throws an exception but you are using it anyways after the `catch` block. 
To avoid this, check `total` for null. 
Dmitry Bychenko provided you with a pretty neat alternative so I'm just going to point out some small things in your code.

1. `Console.ReadLine()` already is a string, this would work:

   `total = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine);`
2. You check `total` twice, once in the outer `if` block and again in the `while` loop. You don't have to do that.
3. Once you get to the second parse attempt within the loop and enter something invalid, an exception will be thrown but you don't handle it.
4. For your own sake, format your code.
5. Try to avoid unnecessary exceptions. If an exception is thrown, the application freezes for a few seconds which neither looks good nor is it fun to use. `TryParse` for example returns `false` if the parse attempt fails.